# Visualforce as msword: special characters aren't visualized correctly

Tags: visualforce, ms-word

I have a requirement in which I have to make a exportable word document from a contract record. I have decided to create a visualforce page with contentType set to application/msword.

I understand that Salesforce offers this as a workaround but there is no official documentation or support (only a help.salesforce page) and they explicitely say that the necessary css/html code needed to visualize a word in a certain way is out of scope for Salesforce support, so I come here to see if anyone knows.

The documents I'm generating are in Spanish, and there are a lot of special characters (ñ, for example, and acute letters)

When I first exported the document, with the text in my html with the special characters added directly, the word shows, for example, the "ñ" character as "Ã±", the "á" as "Ã¡", etc etc.

I thought that using the HTML codes for those characters would the trick "& aacute;", etc etc. But it doesnt. Is there any other way to represent those special characters so the Word engine understands them? Do I have to explicitely define the encoding or something? Any help would be appreciated!

(I tried with the entity name, entity number and HEX code, and nothing works. Do I have to involve CSS into this?)

Comment: Can you try `contentType="application/msword; charset=utf-8"` and see if that helps? It sounds like the encoding or the default encoding is limited to ASCII and specifying the character set should help.

Comment: @nbrown it didn't work sadly :( contentType="application/msword#wordprueba.doc;charset=utf-8"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution:

Adding this did the trick:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
```

Apparently adding the charset specification in the contentType attribute of apex:page doesn't work, but adding it manually in the html head works.

Props to @nbrown for the charset idea.

Comment: FWIW I used to use HTML a lot for Word Docs - it generally works ok as long as you avoid anything particularly fancy!

Comment: @MattLacey yeah, that's what I read, but there isn't a lot of forum threads or questions about exporting visualforce pages as msword documents and I never did this so I had to ask. I believe this special character issue could be encountered by other people and no one asked before so I did, now a solution is available.